# Insert Data in specified column if column value id matches the description of the ID in another table (normalized form)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

In order to do this (in Title Description) it's obvious that it's already a normalized database so an inner join kind of check will be used for sure.

Let's say that we have a customer table and a given customer_ID as a primary key as well as description first name last name etc and on another table (Customer_Sales_History) Customer_ID column also in order to make it searchable query-wise.

UPDATED:
My struggle is that I need to add specific data acquired in an XML(Soap response) format in specific columns but attached to a specific Customer_IDs through a Customer_Name & Customer_Lastname check.

If Customer_Name = "John" and Customer_Lastname = "Martin" then populate salescode productquantity and productdescription with the values

the volume is big (thousands of rows) so that sql might have to be populated as an insertion from another table, im quite new to that type of slqing volume.

```
           Customer Table
Customer_ID | Customer_Name | Customer_Lastname 
1           |  John         | Martin
2           |  Jack         | White
3           |  Don          | Carrera

     Customer_Sales_History Table

Customer_ID | Sales_Code | ProductQuantity | ProductDescription
2           |     X      |        X        |         X
```

In order to INSERT the given data to Customer_Sales_History Table with Customer_ID 2 as a given target I'll have to match the row that Customer_Name = Jack and Customer_Lastname = White and populate Sales_Code Product_Quantity & Product Description.

Comment: So how should that "XML format" look like? What information do you need in there? Do you really need to _insert_ data or do you want to _update_ existing rows in the history table? Where do the values for sales_code, productquantity and productdescription come from? Your customer table does not seem to have that.

Comment: It's a soap response so its like 
<FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
<LastName>White</LastName>
<SalesCode>2000</SalesCode>
<ProductQuantity>2</ProductQuantity>
<ProductDescription>SQL HOW TO FOR DUMMIES</ProductDescription> The thing also is that like this response are like 45.000 others.. so what im trying to do is to create an SQL statement so i wont have to do it manually... besides that i could do with Navicat. no SQL code needed for 1 row.

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. Why can't you use a simple `insert into customer_sales_history (...) values (...)`?

Comment: I can pre-create the table so creation is not an issue in that SQL statement.

Comment: If i simply add them i create duplicates with the already listed customers while what i actually want is to attach the sales to already stored customers. if they already exist.

Comment: Hence the need to match with customer_name customer_lastname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Update ch
set ch.sales_code = ...,
    ch. ProductQuantity =...,
from  Customer_Sales_History ch join Customer c on ch. Customer_ID= c.Customer_ID
where ch.Customer_ID=2
```

Comment: Do **not** specify the target table in the `from` clause of an UPDATE statement unless you want a cross join of that table with itself.

Comment: what you mean? can you write it down?

Comment: It's already written down in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html (See the section about `from_list`)

Comment: "it must appear with an alias in the from_list". so it is ok. isn't it?

Comment: No it's, not - "*Note that the target table must **not** appear in the from_list, unless you intend a self-join*" - your update statement **will** create  a self join which is completely unnecessary and will lead to more rows being updated then intended - it is simply wrong (plus: adtoctor wants to _insert_ data, not update)

Comment: In that i can edit because as in documentation INSERT creates new rows so it is my mistake to use the term. since i want to match already created rows and to simply populate specified columns with the data that derrives from the soap xml responses.

Comment: because of the match of two tables, I thought you means update. so this query will help.just test it

Comment: It almost does the trick but without the First_Name Last_Name Checking as i said the response soap xml data are unaware of the DB structure the only thing that binds the data and customer_table is the description of the client as of name lastname. Remember that we talk for thousands of rows thousands of customers & from the other side also thousands of extra data that needs to be implemented. Even if you find the updated column correctly its like manual data entry... willl take weeks to pass through htem one by one. I've also updated the question in order to give a better picture.

Comment: so just change where clause to :` where Customer_Name = "John" and Customer_Lastname = "Martin"`

Comment: Indeed closest to what i was needed although i'll have to do it for many values so maybe ill have to create a loop with different  where Customer_Name = "John" and Customer_Lastname = "Martin" as i have many customers to put data into.

Comment: you need a cursor for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have declared customer_ID in customer table as Primary key and customer_ID in Customer_Sales_History table as Foreign key, then it will automatically do the checking part. 
So, why do you need to explicitly do the check for customer_id?

Comment: Because my given data are unaware of the DB format they simply give you the description of the customer and that description for example Jack White is the one i have to match in the row in order to insert the new Data.